# Troubles using policies.json to implement default homepage in firefox 60.8.0esr

Tags: json, firefox, batch-processing, group-policy

I am trying to implement a `policies.json` in my Firefox installation directory `distribution` and it seems that it works just fine on my first computer, but when I try it on another computer it doesn't work at all. I am just trying to set a default homepage for the Firefox users in my network.

I know that there is no GPO that rules Firefox on the other machines.

```
{ 
 "policies": {
    "Homepage": {
     "URL": "https://aplusaresearch.sharepoint.com/sites/intranet",
      "StartPage": "homepage"
    }
 }
}
```

`

I tried on Firefox 60.8.0 but there is no `about:policies` so I also installed Firefox 63 and the result is that it doesn't find any `policies.json` file in my Firefox directory.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the `about:policies` page is not available in version 60.8.0.

However, the `distribution/policies.json` file you have provided is valid, and does work with Firefox 60.8.0esr.

Make sure to place the file in `%PROGRAMFILES%\Mozilla Firefox\distribution\policies.json`

---

You can download other old release of Firefox, including 60.8.0esr from here:

```
https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/
```